# didselectrowat Indexpath use two sender and one common segue identifier

Tags: ios, swift

This is my Code in `Xcode`...but I am getting initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Wires_Cables_Details_Menu'.Any solution

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if let  formulation_type_a_menu =
        Wires_Cables_Category_MasterData.instance.getformulations_type_a()[indexPath.row]
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "WC_Formulation_Segue", sender: formulation_type_a_menu)
    }
    else
    {
        let forumulation_type_c_menu = Wires_Cables_Category_MasterData.instance.getformulations_type_c()[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "WC_Formulation_Segue", sender: forumulation_type_c_menu)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation in your `if let` statement does not return an Optional. It will never be `nil` so conditional binding is not necessary. You have 2 paths forward here. You could either modify either `Wires_Cables_Category_MasterData.instance` or `getformulations_type_a()` to return an optional type, or you can find some other condition to decide whether to call `getformulations_type_a()` or `getformulations_type_c()` that doesn't involve conditional binding. The error right now, however, is because you're trying to unwrap an "optional" that isn't actually optional with `if let`